# How to make a new Array of Object using data from backend which is array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, javascript-objects

Hi I am new to Angular and I want to bind my dropdown options with value as

`[ { label: "name", value: "id"} ]`

as in label should have the below names and the values as the below IDs ( in the image )

I have my backend data as

[image]

I want the id and name as my options value for the dropdown.
Please if anyone could guide me

p.s I tried using map function but all I am getting in the options is [object object]

Comment: please paste your code here.

Comment: data  => map(item => {
        this.events = item
      })  I tried using the item[index]['name'] but then it showed some other error, index in the callback function of map

Comment: let list = data.map(item => ({label: item.name, value: item.id}));

Comment: @kinglish sorry, just saw ur answer now. If u want I can remove it.

Comment: @sagat - no problem, but you might consider making a snippet in your answer so OP can see it working.

Comment: will do thx for suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the map function

```
backendData.map(item => ({ label: item.name, value: item.id }));
```

The map function returns a newly created array, that is containing the mapped objects.

Here is a small mvp stackblitz: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zwrnsy?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: yes this works perfectly fine, actually what wrong I was doing is that , I was expecting a Observer of particular class, then I changed it to any, and I was able to convert it , Thanks both of you  Sagat and @Kinglish